# How to store the Captured video and upload in ionic ios

Tags: javascript, ionic3, angular5

I would like to store the captured video and upload in ionic 3 ios app.But i couldn't to do that as I used earlier in android.If anyone find the solution,please share that.

I'm using below code for capturing video.

```
let options: CaptureVideoOptions = { limit: 1,duration: 60};
    this.mediaCapture.captureVideo(options)
    .then((res: MediaFile[]) => {
      let capturedFile = res[0];
      let fileName = capturedFile.name;
      let dir = capturedFile['localURL'].split('/');
      dir.pop();
      let fromDirectory = dir.join('/');      
      var toDirectory = this.file.dataDirectory;

      this.file.copyFile(fromDirectory , fileName , toDirectory , fileName).then((res) => {
        this.storeMediaFiles([{name: fileName, size: capturedFile.size}]);
      },err => {
        console.log('err: ', err);
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use **cdv** path for uploading the video through file transfer plugin..

In above code I'm getting the cdv path in **fromDirectory** and add the filename with it.

In iOS, I didn't save the captured video.But I stored the video in temporary path for uploading.